# How do I use file.Write and file.Read to save player data

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

Im trying to make an experience script. The only thing I can't seem to figure is Data Saving. Im using file.Write and whenever I have my script read the player's level and experience from the data, it doesnt show up. I have my variables xp equal to 0 and level equal to 1. If I wanted to save the number I assigned or any number added to this to equal a new one to a txt file using file.Write as well as having that data read whenever a player spawns, how could I accomplish this?

```
local xp = 0
local level = 1 


local players = player.GetAll()

for k ,v in pairs(players) do
    file.Write("xpdata.txt", xp)
    file.Write("leveldata.txt", level)
end

hook.Add("PlayerSpawn", "leveldata", function()
    file.Read("xpdata.txt", "DATA")
    file.Read("leveldata.txt", "DATA")
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use json.
I can't write now a whole example but you can have a look at this page https://wiki.gideros.rocks/index.php/Start_Here#Save.2Fread_data_persistently
maybe that can help you understand the concept.

Answer (score 0):

What do you expect to happen if you just read a file into nirvana?

```
hook.Add("PlayerSpawn", "leveldata", function()
    file.Read("xpdata.txt", "DATA")
    file.Read("leveldata.txt", "DATA")
end)
```

Here you read two files but you don't do anything with the return values.
`file.Read` returns a string with the files contents if successful.
You need to do something with the return value.

```
local xpData = file.Read("xpdata.txt", "DATA")
if not xpData then
  print("Reading data/xpdata.txt failed!")
else
  print("XP: ", xpData)
end
```

Of course you should store that data per player and make sure each player gets its own xp assigned.

```
local xp = 0
local level = 1
local players = player.GetAll()

for k ,v in pairs(players) do
    file.Write("xpdata.txt", xp)
    file.Write("leveldata.txt", level)
end
```

This doesn't make too much sense as well.
You're writing to the same file for every player. Each loop cycle will overwrite the file of the cycle before.

Also having the same xp and level for each player won't help much.

So either you have one file per player or you have some kind of structure in that common file that allows you to write and read player specific data.

You need to "serialize" your data befor you write it to the file and deserialize it later.

This can be achieved by using two utility functions

https://wiki.facepunch.com/gmod/util.TableToJSON

https://wiki.facepunch.com/gmod/util.JSONToTable

Then you can do something like this

```
local playerData = {}
-- for each player
for k, player in pairs(players) do
  -- add a table with xp and lvl so you can later access it by AccountID 
  playerData[player.AccountID] = {xp = player.xp, lvl = player.lvl}
end
local jsonStr = util.TableToJSON(playerData)
file.Write("playerdata.xp", jsonStr")
```

I'll leave the rest up to you so you can learn something.